# AsyncStorage mergeItem promise returns empty

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, asyncstorage

I have the following `JSON` data structure below:

```
{
  Category1 : { 
      id:1,
      subCategory : [
         {
           pairA: 'JavaScript is?',
           pairB: 'JS',
         },
         {
           pairA: 'Hypertext Markup Language is?',
           pairB: 'HTML',
         },
      ]
  },
  Category2 : { 
      id:2,
      subCategory : [
         {
           pairA: 'Hypetext Transfer Protocol is?',
           pairB: 'HTTP',
         },
         {
           pairA: 'File Transfer Protocol is?',
           pairB: 'FTP',
         },
      ]
  },
}
```

Now, let's say I want to merge the following for `Category1` key.

```
const line = {
  Category1 : { 
      id:1,
      subCategory : [
         {
           pairA: 'JavaScript is?',
           pairB: 'JS',
         },
         {
           pairA: 'Hypertext Markup Language is?',
           pairB: 'HTML',
         },
         {
           pairA: 'Post Office Protocol 3?',
           pairB: 'POP3',
         },
      ]
  },
}
```

Notice I only add the following for `Category1`:

```
         {
           pairA: 'Post Office Protocol 3?',
           pairB: 'POP3',
         },
```

Now, somewhere in my code I called the following action:

```
 this.props.addLineToCategory("Category1", line)
```

And this is the `Redux` **action** itself:

```
 export function addLineToCategory(key, item) {
 console.log("key",key)
 console.log("item",item)
 return (dispatch) => 
 { 
    AsyncStorage.mergeItem(CATEGORY_KEY, JSON.stringify({
       [key]:item
    })).then((data)=>{console.log("Data for dispatch",data); dispatch(addEntry(data)) })
    .catch((error)=>{console.log('Adding line error : ',error)});  
 }   
}
```

Result for `console.log("key",key)`:

```
key Category1
```

Result for `console.log("item",item)`:

```
 item Object {
  "Category1": Object {
     "id":1,
     "subCategory": Array [
        Object {
         {
           pairA: 'JavaScript is?',
           pairB: 'JS',
         },
         {
           pairA: 'Hypertext Markup Language is?',
           pairB: 'HTML',
         },
         {
           pairA: 'Post Office Protocol 3?',
           pairB: 'POP3',
         },
        }
      ]
     }
   }
```

The results so far are as expected. But the returned `Promise` of the `AsyncsStorage.mergeItem()` or in the `console.log("Data for dispatch",data)` is a `null`. I was expecting a merged value of everything but unfortunately it as mentioned a `null`. By the way I am new to `React` and `React Native` as well.

Comment: Don't you need to merge item directly instead of [key]:item?

Comment: You mean without having to use `AsyncStorage`? I have to use `AsyncStorage` for persistence. Unless I am not understanding your question correctly.

Comment: No, what I mean is that in your console.log of item, it already has the key Category1. It seems you are trying to merge "Category1: Category1: {...."

Comment: A ok. You mean just `item` and not `[key]:item`?

Comment: Yep (inserting garbage to complete comment)

Comment: I did but it did not work. Thanks for your suggestion and the humour as well ;-)

Comment: Weird How about mergeItem("Category1", JSON.stringify({item.Category1}))? Actually, did you save and load the data to confirm the Storage is working?